# How to print all data in datatable with XY scroll bar in JSF primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have datatable(PrimeFaces) in my project and i want to print all the data in it and the datatable has XY scrol bar so when i click at print button only the visible data which is visible in datatable is printed and the data which is in scroll will not printed and i cant post here project picture beacuse it is complicated so please sujjest me what to do?
thanks in advance

[image: this is picture example]

this is example : the data which is shown in picture only this data is printed and the data which is hide beacuse of scroll bar will not printed so please suggest me...

Answer (score -1):

IMHO the best approach in your case is to export the table data to pdf and print from the file.

Primefaces has a [data exporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporter.jsf) component that you can use.

Comment: you are right but i have to print whole web page not the pdf file

Answer (score -1):

Use a print specific view. Duplicate your page and set the table without pagination and height attributes (hope you don't have tens of thousands objects in your lists). Last step would be to use CSS @print to style your page how you want it. And add a print button so it's easier to use.

```
<a class="btn btn-mini" href="javascript: window.print();">
    <i class="icon-print"></i>
    <span>Print</span>
</a>
```

Comment: i cant do this beacuse data must be in table with this layout which i had post in question

Comment: in what layout? you only want to see two columns? I guess you want to print all the data, so what happens if you don't use any scroll parameters neither from PrimeFaces nor from css? Is it too wide?